# is there anytthing way to set a variable to accept only two values in oracle SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

This is my code and I want to set my variable `Account_Type` to accept only two values.

```sql
CREATE TABLE AccountRrequest(
  RequestId NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
  Branch VARCHAR2(15),
  Account_Type VARCHAR2(15),       --> Account_Type
  Title VARCHAR2(4),
  FirstName VARCHAR2(15),
  LastName VARCHAR2(15),
  Birthday DATE DEFAULT (MM-DD-YYYY),
  WorkPhone NUMBER(10),
  HomePhone NUMBER(10),
  Address VARCHAR2(30),
  State VARCHAR2(15),
  Zip NUMBER(10),
  Email VARCHAR2(30),
  Status VARCHAR2(10) DEFAULT 'Entered'
);
```

Comment: Those are **columns** not "variables"

Comment: Just as a side observation, telephone numbers are not NUMBERs.  They are character strings that, by _most_ conventions, are limited to the ten numeric CHARACTERS.  If you define them as a NUMBER type, you risk losing leading zeros, which means the number you end up with would be incorrect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways of doing it.

- Firstly, you could us a `CHECK` constraint to limit the values;

```sql
CREATE TABLE AccountRequest(
  RequestId    NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
  Branch       VARCHAR2(15),
  Account_Type VARCHAR2(15),
  Title        VARCHAR2(4),
  FirstName    VARCHAR2(15),
  LastName     VARCHAR2(15),
  Birthday     DATE,
  WorkPhone    VARCHAR2(10),
  HomePhone    VARCHAR2(10),
  Address      VARCHAR2(30),
  State        VARCHAR2(15),
  Zip          NUMBER(10),
  Email        VARCHAR2(30),
  Status       VARCHAR2(10) DEFAULT 'Entered',
  CONSTRAINT AccountRequest__Acount_Type__CHK
    CHECK ( Account_Type IN ( 'value1', 'value2' ) )
);
```

- Alternatively, you could put the acceptable values in another table and use a referential constraint.

```sql
CREATE TABLE account_types (
  account_type VARCHAR2(15),
  CONSTRAINT account_types__account_type__pk PRIMARY KEY (account_type)
);

INSERT INTO Account_Types ( Account_Type ) VALUES ( 'value1' );
INSERT INTO Account_Types ( Account_Type ) VALUES ( 'value2' );

CREATE TABLE AccountRequest(
  RequestId    NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
  Branch       VARCHAR2(15),
  Account_Type VARCHAR2(15) NOT NULL,
  Title        VARCHAR2(4),
  FirstName    VARCHAR2(15),
  LastName     VARCHAR2(15),
  Birthday     DATE,
  WorkPhone    VARCHAR2(10),
  HomePhone    VARCHAR2(10),
  Address      VARCHAR2(30),
  State        VARCHAR2(15),
  Zip          NUMBER(10),
  Email        VARCHAR2(30),
  Status       VARCHAR2(10) DEFAULT 'Entered',
  CONSTRAINT AccountRequest__Acount_Type__FK
    FOREIGN KEY ( Account_Type ) REFERENCES Account_Types (Account_Type)
);
```

*Note: You probably don't want to use a `NUMBER` data type for phone numbers; although they are composed of numeric characters they, often, start with a `0` and a `NUMBER` column will not store that.*

*Note: A `DATE` is a binary data-type that **ALWAYS** has year, month, day, hour, minute and second components and does **NOT** store any format. You cannot use `DEFAULT` to set a format.*

Answer (score 2):

There is a way, it is called a **check constraint** (see lines #5 - 7) (it is set to accept `type1` or `type2`; other values aren't allowed):

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE AccountRrequest
  2  (
  3     RequestId      NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
  4     Branch         VARCHAR2 (15),
  5     Account_Type   VARCHAR2 (15)
  6                      CONSTRAINT ch_acctype CHECK
  7                         (account_type IN ('type1', 'type2')),
  8     Title          VARCHAR2 (4),
  9     FirstName      VARCHAR2 (15),
 10     LastName       VARCHAR2 (15),
 11     Birthday       DATE,                           -- DEFAULT (MM - DD - YYYY),
 12     WorkPhone      NUMBER (10),
 13     HomePhone      NUMBER (10),
 14     Address        VARCHAR2 (30),
 15     State          VARCHAR2 (15),
 16     Zip            NUMBER (10),
 17     Email          VARCHAR2 (30),
 18     Status         VARCHAR2 (10) DEFAULT 'Entered'
 19  );

Table created.
    
SQL> insert into accountrrequest (requestid, account_type) values (1, 'type3');
insert into accountrrequest (requestid, account_type) values (1, 'type3')
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02290: check constraint (SCOTT.CH_ACCTYPE) violated


SQL> insert into accountrrequest (requestid, account_type) values (1, 'type1');

1 row created.

SQL>
```

Also, default "format" can't be set the way you did it so I commented it in line #11. Default value could be e.g. `sysdate`, but  it doesn't make sense here because I presume nobody was born "today", the day when you'll be inserting rows into that table. If so, you'd

```
Birthday       DATE DEFAULT TRUNC(SYSDATE),
```

Furthermore, it is not a "variable" that accepts some values in this case - it is a **column**.

Finally, looks like table name has a typo. Is it really `AccountRrequest` (with 2 "R" in "Rr"equest?)

Comment: the name of my table are typo , you're right , i just wanna add some question?
is there anything way to create a log on this table for every records that has been rejected by the table , using PL/SQL ?

Comment: @BROX That is outside the scope of this question; you would be better asking a new question.